# Which sample code is best to use?

Tags: chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I would like to create an Android app that is basically a chat.
I have read many articles on the web until I found *QuickBlox*.

(I admit I didn't understand exactly how it works and how to use it and I'm new in mobile app develiping).

I am following this [tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Minute_Guide#Welcome_to_QuickBlox.2C_where_you_can_get_your_cloud_backend_running_in_just_5_minutes.21_All_you_need_is_to:) and now I should download the sample code.
I saw that there are different types:

1. Simple Android Chat code sample
2. Simple Android WebRTC (VideoChat) code sample
3. Simple Android Location code sample
4. Simple Android Push Notifications (Messages) code sample
5. Simple android Custom Objects (key value data store) code sample
6. Simple android Users authentication code sample
7. Simple android content storage and update code sample

I would like some advice on which is the best in my case.

My app is a "simple" chat app that allows a registration (for example, using social networks like Google+ and Facebook) and orders the users based on proximity. 
So if the user X is located in Paris, registered users will see the app in order of proximity (eg before those who live in Saint-Denis and then those live in Orleans).
For the moment I'm only interested to send/receive text, not multimedia content such as photos and videos.

So I'm undecided whether it is better to use between "*Simple Chat Android code sample*", "*Simple Android Location code sample*" or "*Simple Android Push Notifications (Messages) code sample*".

From what I understand, push notifications can be added at a later time, or am I wrong?
I hope I have said all that is necessary for the selection..

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need all three in order to do what you want:

1. *Simple Chat Android code sample* - helps with almost everything involved in normal chat applications(send and receive messages,emoji support,typing status etc). However it doesn't include multimedia messaging and push notification support.
2. *Simple Android Push Notifications (Messages) code sample* - basically shows how to send and receive push notifications. Which can be added anytime you want. The chat will work fine without it.

3.*Simple Android Location code sample* - shows how the location api works and can be used for what you described.

Hope this helps.